# Boolean for API Get request, with default. Y/N/All or true/false/all

Tags: api, rest, api-design

I'm implementing a filter for a boolean value, but I want to have a default value, so for example.

```
parameter omitted - returns where isPublished=true
isPublished=true - return's where isPublished=true
isPublished=false - return's where isPublished=false
```

What If I want to return everything? I could do isPublished=all but some have complained that this is confusing as its not then a true boolean.

I could also go with Y/N/All or Either or Both

What are others views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `boolean` that restricts the values to `true` and `false`, you could consider using an enumeration and a parameter called `status` or something similar to send its value to the server:

```
status = PUBLISHED | NOT_PUBLISHED | ALL
```

If the `status` parameter is ommited, assume its value is `PUBLISHED`. Otherwise, use the value provided in the parameter.

In the long run, using an enumeration will give you the possibility of expanding the available status.

Comment: I like that. Thanks!